# Changing </BR> to newline in XSLT

Tags: xslt, newline, xslt-2.0

I have the following XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
exclude-result-prefixes="date">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="//Mail">
    <html>
      <body>
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of xml:space="preserve" select="body"/>
      </p>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the "body" I want to put the following text :

```html
Beste, <BR/><BR/>
Dit is een automatische mail m.b.t. een registratie in MyRiziv voor de groepering '{0}' met RIZIV-nummer {1}:<BR/><BR/>
```

Now when I insert that into the XSLT the `<BR/>` keep appearing. I would like them to be replaced by a newline.

The output I expect would be:

> Beste,
>
> Dit is een automatische mail m.b.t. een registratie in MyRiziv voor de
>   groepering '{0}' met RIZIV-nummer {1}:
>
> The {0} and {1} will be replaced with actual values.

I use the following C# code to do the transformation :

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"));

        XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Mail");

        XmlNode childElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("salutation");
        childElement.InnerText = GetTranslation("Salutation"); 
        rootNode.AppendChild(childElement);

        childElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("body");
        switch (emailType)
        {
            case EmailType.GeneralDataUpdated:
                childElement.InnerText = CreateGeneralDataUpdatedBody(newHci, oldHci, requestor);
                break;
        }
        rootNode.AppendChild(childElement);

XslCompiledTransform xsltTransformer = new XslCompiledTransform();

        using (XmlReader xsltRdr = XmlReader.Create(format))
        {
            xsltTransformer.Load(xsltRdr);
        }

        xmlStream.Position = 0;
        StringWriter results = new StringWriter();

        using (XmlReader xmlRdr = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream))
        {
            xsltTransformer.Transform(xmlRdr, new XsltArgumentList(), results);
        }

        return results.ToString();
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It isn't clear to me exactly what HTML output you expect.  Can you include your expected output in the question?

Comment: What stops you from not putting new lines instead of `<br>` in the xslt to begin with?

Comment: Are your `<br />` tags actually inside a `<![CDATA[]>` tag in your input XML? You really do need to edit your question to show your input. Thank you.

Comment: @TimC The input I'm sending is actually : Ceci est un email automatique concernant un enregistrement dans MyInami pour le groupement '{0}' avec numéro INAMI {1}:<BR/><BR/>
Le {4}, {2} {3} a modifié les données de votre groupement.<BR/><BR/>
---------------------------------- <BR/><BR/>

Comment: So, the `CreateGeneralDataUpdatedBody` is creating the input? By doing `innerText` you are adding it as text, so there won't be any `<BR/>` tags in your input, but a string of 5 characters. You could try `innerXml` instead, but  `CreateGeneralDataUpdatedBody` would need to return well-formed XML (i.e. have a single root element).

Comment: Even if you don't have a well-formed document with a single root element, you can always create an `XmlDocumentFragment` from your `xmlDoc`, then set its `InnerXml` to the fragment of XML you have and `AppendChild` the document fragment to that body element you create. Then the approach  in the answer by Rupesh should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply-template` instead of `value-of` for body, so that you can handle `BR` in output.

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="//Mail">
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="body"/>
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BR">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

See transformation on http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/pPgCcoq

Comment: I tried your solution but I'm still getting the same result. I'm not getting the newline and the BR is still being displayed

Comment: @BartSchelkens, See transformation on [http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/pPgCcoq](http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/pPgCcoq)

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work on my code. don't get the newlines

Comment: @BartSchelkens, will you put your all input here or [http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/pPgCcoq](http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/pPgCcoq)